# Htacces mobile redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirection

im need to change the template of my site if mobile is detected but im getting a redirect loop. this is my htacces code. Anny help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (GoogleTV|android|mobile|blackberry|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|motorola|netfront|nokia|obigo|
openweb|opera.mini|palm|psp|sanyo|sch|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|
wap|webos|windows.ce) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/?set_the_template=mobile_template [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please reformat your question (there is online help available), as it stands it is almost unreadable.

Comment: @vonbrand you know you can edit his question as well, right?

Comment: @EEAA, yes; but I have no idea what OP is trying to say, and I don't want to misinterpret the question.

Comment: Shouldn't your application be doing this? What if I want to see your full site and not the mobile site?

Answer (score 0):

The way it stands now is that every time someone with a user-agent listed in your list, they will be redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/?set_the_template=mobile_template`. And when they try to access that, they are redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/?set_the_template=mobile_template`. And so on, ad infinitum. This is a loop.

I'd advise you to do this in some other manner, possibly by setting an environment variable and letting your application serve up the right template. Or, better still, by following Michael Hampton's advice and doing this within the application, including letting the user choose to see the full site.

If you really really do want to do this with mod_rewrite, you need to add a condition to exclude clients that already have the `?set_the_template=mobile_template`. An example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} != set_the_template=mobile
```